# "Android Design Icons" do not match system icons

Tags: android

I am trying to use the action bar icons provided by android at 
http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack

For some reason, neither "Holo Dark", nor "Holo Light" match the system icon color. For example:

Here are 3 icons:

[image: Action Bar Icons]

- The left is holo_dark/xhdpi/9_av_upload.png
- The middle is the system icon provided by `@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload`
- The right is holo_light/xhdpi/9_av_upload.png from that download

The light is lighter that the system icon, but the dark is darker than the system icon. Where can I find icons matching the actual system icons?

I am seeing this behavior on both my test phone (HTC Evo LTE) as well as in the emulator running 4.0.3

Comment: What is the "system" that you are comparing against? An emulator? A device?

Comment: Did you run your experiment on an emulator, or a Nexus series device? IOW, how do you know that the problem isn't something specific to your HTC Evo LTE? In theory, device manufacturers are not supposed to be messing with `Theme.Holo`, but, in theory, I should have hair. :-)

Comment: BTW, at least for `ic_menu_upload`, your Android SDK installation will have copies as well.

Comment: I will try it in an emulator.

Comment: Upload isn't actually the problem, the one I need is copy. I was just using upload because it let me illustrate the difference betweens the icon packs and the installed icon.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? If you're targeting a post-HC device, that icon (along with the Holo themes) is guaranteed to exist and you don't have to ship it with your app. The colour mismatch could be anything from colour space conversion to the fact that designers did those sprite sheets after the assets had been handed over. Also, are you sure your icon is opaque?

Comment: The problem is that the icons in the icon pack are a slightly different color than the system icons and system only provides a small subset of the icons. In my specific case, the only missing icon is the "copy" one but it stands out pretty badly when nested between the system "share" and the menu icon.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for: on your hard drive, `sdk/platforms/android-X/data/res/`

Comment: That does seem to be what I am looking for! Why aren't all of these available through `@android:drawable/` the way upload is?

Comment: @Sionide21 Well, do you want them to be? Your resource folder would be over 20 MBs, and that too for just one platform version :). Posting this as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons(and other resources) can be found in android sdk directory on your hard drive. Follow this path:

`android_sdk_directory / sdk / platforms / android-VERSION / data / res`